# Passing state to preact component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, preact

I have a newcomer to react/preact. I have a simple app that fetches weather forecast from an API and I want this data to be passed to a chart component (precharts). The problem I have is when this chart gets rendered, the data has not yet been fetched and I get type errors, because I am already trying to process it. I saw another question where the top answer suggested to conditionally assign null instead of the component to a variable when my parent component's state is not yet evaluated.

In the parent component, I have the following method that sets the state to be passed (it is called by the parent's constructor):

```
parseHourly = (parsed_json) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var h = parsed_json['hourly_forecast'][i]['FCTTIME']['hour'];
        var t = parsed_json['hourly_forecast'][i]['temp']['metric'];
        var pair = {hour: h, temperature: t};
        this.state.temps.push(pair);
    }
}
```

This is the parent's render method where I create the chart:

```
render() {
    let myChart;
    if(this.state.temps) {
        myChart = <Chart temps={this.state.temps}/>
    } else {
        myChart = null
    }

    return (
        <div class={ style.container }>
            ...
            { myChart }
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the Chart component, I'm trying to access `this.props.temps` directly in the `render()` method, but I end up with the value being `undefined`.
What am I doing wrong? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `setState` in the `parseHourly` function? It should be something like this: `this.setState(state => ({ temps: [...state.temps, pair] }))`. This is only a guess, I'll write an answer if this ends up solving the issue

Comment: @kingdaro to be honest, I'm not quite sure. In the constructor, I did `this.state.temps = [];` I'm following the boilerplate code I was given, because again, I'm a total newcomer. Is there a difference between using `setState()` and setting the field directly?

Comment: Using `setState()` is the proper way of notifying React/Preact that it needs to perform a re-render. Setting or mutating the variables directly doesn't do anything, as react isn't watching for changes on them that way.

Comment: At this point, is `if(this.state.temps){...}` needed anymore? Thanks for you reply btw, @FisNaN has already submitted an answer, but this is helpful nevertheless.

Comment: As long as it's always an array, you can probably remove it. And sure :)

Answer (score 3):

You need use `setState` function, create a copy of previous state and then push the new item in.
Please refer to React lifecycle doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

The code below is how to setState in your case. However, you have to put this function at where React can update state:

```js
parseHourly = (parsed_json) = > {
  const bufferTemps = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.temps));
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const h = parsed_json['hourly_forecast'][i]['FCTTIME']['hour'];
    const t = parsed_json['hourly_forecast'][i]['temp']['metric'];
    const pair = {
      hour: h,
      temperature: t
    };
    bufferTemps.push(pair);
  }
  this.setState({
    temps: bufferTemps
  });
}
```

**Note:**
`const bufferTemps = [...this.state.temps]` will not create a deep copy for each item, and it is not supposed to do `this.state.temps.push(pair)`
To solve this, I use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.temps))` to create a deep clone.

Comment: It works well inside the parent class, but when I instantiate the chart: `<Chart temps={this.state.temps}/>` and try to `alert(props.temps)` in the Chart constructor, I get an empty alert window.

Comment: If you take a look on the link I attached. `constuctor` is before `componentWillMount` in React lifecycle You can try console.log from `componentDidMount` and see what's happened.

Comment: (I deleted the previous comment) It logs an empty Array.

Comment: @JanParzydło If you create a codesandbox, I might able to help https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but it's going to be to complicated for me to condense the project and make it run there. Again, I am a beginner and I'm building on top of some custom boilerplate code which I don't fully understand.

Comment: Just to reiterate - when I log props from the chart's `render()`, they are undefined at first, but after 2 or so calls, they show up. Right now I would happily settle for a quick workaround.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kpkj3jx0o I just built a timer to demonstrate how to setState repeatly and how to update value inside a child component. Does it help?

Comment: Without looking at your code, I guess you dive into the problem when setInterval clashed with async API. Because the time can't wait. The common solution is to add a received data flag. Use it to  reset the timer if the data hasn't arrived. But all these assumptions don't reflect on your post. So I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're initializing `this.state.temps = []`, but in your `render()` method you're checking `if (this.state.temps)`.  An empty Array in JS is truthy (`==true`), so the check will always pass.

Try this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.temps = [];
  }
  // ... etc ...
  render() {
    let myChart
    // if we have any temperatures:
    if (this.state.temps.length>0) {
      myChart = <Chart temps={this.state.temps} />
    }
    return <div class={style.container}>{myChart}</div>
  }
}

class Chart extends Component {
  render() {
    // now we know temps will be an Array of 1 or more items:
    console.log(this.props.temps)
  }
}
```